# ReactJS passing object instead of function inside onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am brand new to React and almost everything related to it. I am still learning the MVC pattern. I am just taking the examples on the React homepage and trying to extend them, but I'm running into an error when I try to add a "onClick" to a span tag that I'm including with every todo.

Here is what I'm doing: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/11884/

And here is the offending code block:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    markComplete: function(event){
        alert("geelo");
    },

    render: function(){
        var createItem = function(itemText, index){
            return (
                <li key={index + itemText}>
                    {itemText}<span id="markComplete" onClick={this.markComplete}>X</span>
                </li>
            );
        };
        return <ul id="list-container">{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>
    }
});
```

Specifically I'm trying to get `markComplete` to fire from the following `onClick={this.markComplete}`

If I click on the "markComplete" span I get the following error:

> Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object.

I can not find a solution on my own, and I've been struggling for awhile and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I would be very grateful! Thank you so much!

Comment: The codepen linked, when I hit "Add ToDo" it console.logs but does not bring me somewhere I can mark complete.  Is that just me?

Comment: Now it's putting nothing onto the DOM

Comment: This link: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/11885/ ?

Comment: That one is working, I'm not getting an Error though, it's just not doing anything.  Give me a moment to fiddle with it.

Comment: At the point where your onclick handler is being called, `this` is no longer in scope. You'll need to `bind` it (or something) to make this work. (i think?)

Comment: @ray: I yanked any parameters out of markComplete and turned it into a console.log.  And I'm not getting anything...

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'm still trying to fix, I'm trying to find more information about what you're talking about @ray I'll comment if I can find anything. Thanks again!

Comment: I solved your issue for you, check out my answer.  It should've worked awhile ago but I was having an issue with JSFiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your solution code:

You have to bind `this` to createItem otherwise it cannot reference the markComplete function of your React class.
Also, onClick is capitalized.

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    markComplete: function() {
        console.log("geelo");
        alert("ANYTHING");
    },

render: function(){ 
        var createItem = function(itemText, index){
            return (
                <li key={index + itemText}>
                    {itemText}<span id="markComplete" onClick={this.markComplete}>X</span>
                </li>
            );
        };
        return <ul id="list-container">{this.props.items.map(createItem.bind(this))}</ul>
    }
});
```